# Divs aren't aware of screen resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First div is a category and the second div contains some photos.

[image]

I wanted to do something that when user clicks on an image the first div move 0.7 of the screen width to right and all images in second div disappear, so I wrote:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    var my_width = screen.width * 0.7;
    $(".second_div").find("img").hide();
    $(".first_div").css({
      "transform": "translate(" + my_width + "px,0px)",
      "-webkit-transform": "translate(" + my_width + "px,0px)",
      "-ms-transform": "translate(" + my_width + ",0px)"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.first_div {
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_div col-md-1">
  //some code
</div>
<div class="second_div col-md-11>
           //some codes
</div>
```

When its full screen it works right, but when I resize the window and try again the first div won't be located at where it supposed to (0.7 Of screen width) What's wrong?

Comment: and also what happens to bootstrap columns?

Comment: I mean that when transition happens the first div moves into second one and all the photos will hide. now the division is changed?

Comment: What should I do to put a div on the left side of the first div after transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for window width I would use the following:

```
var my_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * 0.7;
```

this is the same (cross-browser compatible) solution used by jQuery's `$.width()`

For more info on different methods of getting width, see this [link](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/).

Comment: Thanx but it didnt work  in this [link](http://qeshmbook.com/test.html) click on the picture below and try resizing the window

Comment: in the link, you are still using `var my_width = screen.width * 0.7;`. Changing it to what is shown in my answer fixes it at any size. If you are saying that resizing after the animation is complete doesn't look how you want it, that is another issue entirely. Using just the animation you have so far will not provide a responsive experience.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a mistake! thank you so much about the help

Comment: so what kind of animation makes it responsive?

Comment: i was going to write a $(window).resize , do you have a better idea?

Comment: after the animation is complete you could position the element with percentages or `float: right` like you normally. Basically your element is currently left-aligned. when your animation takes place, it is still left aligned. It is is just "translated" to the right. This is why grabbing the left edge of the browser to resize moves the div, but grabbing the right side has no effect.

Comment: what you really want to do is design classes for how you want the page to display without any animations at all. These classes will be easier to accomodate for resizing. After you have that, then try and make the transitions from one class to another smooth via animation

Comment: Thank you so much they were so useful thnx again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the window's inner width instead of the screen width, so that it's relative to the size of the viewport. replace

```js
var my_width = screen.width * 0.7 ;
```

with:

```js
var my_width = window.innerWidth * 0.7 ;
```

See an example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWWEKO

Comment: But when i resize the window it wont change its location! maybe i should write a $(window).resize(function(){ }); too. thank you anyway!